# Update inside Trigger fails because of incorrect settings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm updating one column using trigger but I am getting below error .

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct
>   for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations.

Kindly advice me how to solve.

Thanks,

PraveenKumar.K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable the connection settings:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
```

OR

Open the properties of server. Select the tab Connections. And check the `numeric round abort` option.